# How to reload a record where the sti_key column changes during an update to a Sequel Single Table Inheritance (STI) row

Tags: ruby, sequel, sti

So lets say I have a table that's setup with Single Table Inheritance:

```rb
class Employee < Sequel::Model
  plugin :single_table_inheritance, :kind

  class Staff < self; end
  class Manager < self; end
end
```

and I create the new record and then subsequently want to update the employee role, like so:

```rb
employee = Employee::Manager.create
employee.update(kind: "staff")
```

The issue I'm having is that `employee.class` still returns `Employee::Manager` instead of `Employee::Staff` and doing a `employee.reload` results in a `Sequel::NoExistingObject: Record not found`.
Looking at the resulting sql its obvious that's its still trying to find the record using the old type:

```sql
SELECT * FROM "employees" WHERE (("employees"."kind" IN ('manager')) AND ("id" = 1)) LIMIT 1
```

The only way I've been able to get around this is to reload the record from the id:

```rb
employee = Employee[employee.id]
```

Am I missing something or this the only way to refresh the updated record?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all according to your example, you are doing your update in wrong way.
It should be like

```rb
employee = Employee::Manager.create
employee.update(kind: "Employee::Staff")
```

because `Employee` is like a namespace in your example.

And then you can load it class, by calling `sti_load` on class. there is some variations

```rb
em = em.class.sti_load(em) #=> #<Employee::Staff @values={...}>
# or
em = Employee.sti_load(em) #=> #<Employee::Staff @values={...}>
# or
em = Employee::Staff.sti_load(em) #=> #<Employee::Staff @values={...}>
```